# Is there a way to add bash commands to PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm really enjoying some of the new multi-repo tools in PhpStorm.  It's made my composer setup much simpler.  (no more paths in dev)

However, now that I can git any of my composer packages from any project - it would help to have some better shortcut commands and combination commands in the PhpStorm menu system.

Is there a way in Storm to macro together a few git commands, and add that to the menu system?

Comment: External Tools? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@LazyOne provided a great lead - "External Tools".  Thanks.
Here is a more up-to-date documentation
 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-tools-external-tools.html

Based on external tools, my solution was:

1. Create a bash script in my home directory (not in the project).
2. (OSX) PhpStorm > Preferences >> Tools > External Tools
3. click [+]
4. Program: /Users/YOUR-USER/PhpStorm/GitStuff.sh
5. Working Dir: $ProjectFileDir$

$ProjectFileDir$ will be inserted by storm if you leave that field blank.

Remember to `chmod +x /Users/YOUR-USER/PhpStorm/GitStuff.sh`